# Why is it recommended to use 4 spaces instead of tab in Ubuntu's Text Editor?

Tags: python, text-editor

When I use tabs I receive

`TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

However when I replace it with 4 spaces it resolves the issue. Can someone explain why there is an error when tab and 4 spaces look visually the same.

Comment: "Can someone explain why there is an error when tab and 4 spaces look visually the same." - they look the same with your editor settings, but not with someone else's.

Comment: Pep 8 (the official python style guide) recommends spaces ... See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabs and spaces are two different characters, rendered the same on screen. Tab has no agreement on how wide a tab character can be, it may occupy width of 8,4 2 and it is configurable as well.

Python expects the indentation in all the lines to be same as the first line, be it 1 space, 4 spaces or 1 tab etc. Use of tab won't give you an error, inconsistency in different lines will.

Answer (score 0):

A tab could be a different number of columns depending on your environment, but space is always one column.

The use of spaces is recommended especially in the python programming language to avoid editor-to-editor mistakes.

> Python 3 disallows mixing the use of tabs and spaces for indentation.
>
> Python 2 code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be
> converted to using spaces exclusively.

You should also check [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).